# WebSocket-node timeout parameter

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have implemented sockets using WebSocket-node package, now I am trying to set timeout so that if a socket is idle then it should get closed

While getting the detail of connection.socket

```
"console.log(connection.socket);"
```

I got below output

```
_events: 
   { end: [ [Object], [Function] ],
     finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
     _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
     drain: [ [Function: ondrain], [Function: socketOnDrain], [Function] ],
     timeout: [Function],
     error: [Function],
     close: [Function],
     pause: [Function],
     resume: [Function],
     data: [Function],
     readable: [Function] },
  _maxListeners: 10,
  _writableState: 
   { highWaterMark: 16384,
     objectMode: false,
     needDrain: false,
     ending: false,
     ended: false,
     finished: false,
     decodeStrings: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     length: 0,
     writing: false,
     sync: false,
     bufferProcessing: false,
     onwrite: [Function],
     writecb: null,
     writelen: 0,
     buffer: [] },
  writable: true,
  allowHalfOpen: true,
  onend: null,
  destroyed: false,
  errorEmitted: false,
  bytesRead: 950,
  _bytesDispatched: 184,
  _pendingData: null,
  _pendingEncoding: '',
  server: 
   { domain: null,
     _events: 
      { request: [Function],
        connection: [Function: connectionListener],
        clientError: [Function],
        upgrade: [Function] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _connections: 2,
     connections: [Getter/Setter],
     _handle: 
      { fd: 11,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        onconnection: [Function: onconnection],
        owner: [Circular] },
     _usingSlaves: false,
     _slaves: [],
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
     timeout: 120000,
     _connectionKey: '4:0.0.0.0:8000' },
```

As per the above output it seems timeout is set to 120000ms which means 2 mins but my socket is not getting close after 2 mins. Can you guys please help how to change this parameter and also to make sure connection gets close after that stipulated time.